# In Python, how to view the percentage of missing values per each column?

Tags: python, dataframe, missing-data

I am a new Data Scientist, and I am trying to write a code that will calculate the percentage of missing values per each column in a data frame.

Here is a reproducible code:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame([[None, 2, 3],
                     [4, None, 6],
                     [7, 8, None]])
```

In this code, each column contains 33.3% of missing values. The code that I developed to try to solve my own problem is as follows:

```
my_df.isnull().sum() / my_df.count()
```

This code outputs that there are 0.5 for percentage of missing values per column, because as I learned by developing this code the function count() does not consider missing values and counts only non-null values.

How can I overcome this problem and get the correct answer to this problem that states that there the % of missing values per each column is 0.33, and not 0.5?

Thank you!

Comment: Count the index and multiply by number of columns

Comment: For the column-wise percent: `my_df.isnull().sum() / len(my_df)`. For the total dataframe: `my_df.isnull().sum().sum() / (len(my_df) * len(my_df.columns))`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing both ways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try:

```
my_df.isnull().sum()/len(my_df)
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

You have it in front of you -- assuming that you want to use your existing code as a starting point.  `count` omits the null values, but you counted them in the numerator.  Simply add that value to the denominator:

```
my_df.isnull().sum() / ( my_df.count() + my_df.isnull().sum() )
```

Optimization should cause the generated code to cache the `sum` result, making only one chain of calls.

Better yet, use `len` to get the denominator; the resulting code is much easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for this solution and for explaining both methods. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet of code. This should help identify the percent missing rounded to the nearest percent.

```py
percent_missing = (df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending = False) * 100 / len(df)).round(2)
percent_missing
```